# Parallelize scraping with Puppeteer: open multiple links in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, promise, es6-promise, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer in order to scrape several web pages.

My idea is to open several tabs (using the command "browser.newPage ()") and then pass several X links to these pages in order to parallelize the work.

The problem is that sometimes the program works correctly and sometimes it doesn't (the program gets stuck and the page error timeout is throw).

My idea is that probably I'm doing something wrong in handling the promises but I can't understand what the problem is.
I'm following the code example I founded at this [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/471).

```
const promises=[];
let totBrowserInstances = 3;
//instancesLinksMatrix[totBrowserInstances][linksToScrape] 
// matrix where all the links to scrape are stored, it is created in previous part of the code; 

for(let i=0; i<totBrowserInstances; i++){
    console.log('Page ID Spawned', i);
    promises.push(browser.newPage()
    .then(async (page) => {
        for(let j=0; j<instancesLinksMatrix[i].length; j++){
            await page.goto(instancesLinksMatrix[i][j], {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}); // start as soon as the DOM is ready

            await page.evaluate(() => {
                return document.querySelector('.competizione .pagina h3').innerText;
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log('response: ' + result);
            });
        }
    }));
}
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: You definitely should add error message to the question, without it we will just be guessing, especially since sometimes the code works.

Comment: @Vaviloff thanks for you suggestion! I'm going to add the error message as soon as I continue to work on the project. But as I said a "normal" error about the expiration of the page timeout is throw (default Puppeteer page timeout error).

Comment: Well then page.evaluate probably doesn't find what it's looking for.

Comment: But why sometimes it works (so I believe that page.evaluate finds what it's looking for) and sometimes it doesn't work (so I believe that page.evaluate DOESN'T finds what it's looking for)? Im curious to understand the reason. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Do pages absolutely never change and always contain `.competizione .pagina h3`?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure about that. That's the reason why I thought I was probably doing some mistake handling promises/await/async.

Comment: Try logging **everything** so that you will know what URLs produce errors, after how much iterations, if there are REALLY those elements you're after, etc.